# Getting error message from cron but no clue why - can anyone help?

Tags: drupal, error

I'm getting the following message about 3 or 4 times a day from cron. Nothing is showing up in the error log and I'm puzzled.  This follows moving the site from one host to another which must be a clue.  Civi is working fine except for this error message. The site is Drupal based, release 5.19.4 and PHP 7.3.15.
After putting in the line suggested by Demerit, here's the new trace, the problem occurred once today.

**Warning**:  array_intersect_assoc(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, string given in **/home/example/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/SettingsMetadata.php** on line **150**

**Warning**:  array_intersect_assoc(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, string given in **/home/example/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/SettingsMetadata.php** on line **150**

**Warning**:  array_intersect_assoc(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, string given in **/home/example/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/SettingsMetadata.php** on line **150**

**Warning**:  array_intersect_assoc(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, string given in **/home/example/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/SettingsMetadata.php** on line **150**

**Warning**:  session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in **/home/example/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Session.php** on line **124**

And here what was in ConfigAndLog at the time the problem occurred

Mar 18 02:15:02  [info] ddd DD

Mar 18 02:15:02  [info] month

Mar 18 02:15:02  [info] 500

Mar 18 02:15:02  [info] en_GB

Mar 18 02:15:02  [warning] Deprecated Path: There is a setting (generate_schema_and_data) not correctly defined. You may see unpredictability due to this. CRM_Core_Setting::setItems
Array
(
    [civi.tag] => deprecated
)

Mar 18 02:15:04  [warning] Deprecated Path: There is a setting (generate_schema_and_data) not correctly defined. You may see unpredictability due to this. CRM_Core_Setting::setItems
Array
(
    [civi.tag] => deprecated
)

Comment: To debug, just before line 149 add `if (is_string($fieldValues)) { CRM_Core_Error::debug_log_message($fieldValues); }` and then that should at least give a clue in ConfigAndLog as to what.

Comment: Thanks - have done so, will let you know

Comment: That caused a fatal error, but revealed the problem?

Comment: Here's the trace partly edited to keep within the character limit:
 <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Civi\Core\CRM_Core_Error' not found in /home/example/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core
#2 /home/example/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/SettingsManager.php(118): Civi\Core\SettingsManager-&gt;getDefaults('domain')
#3 /home/examplen/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Config.php(126):

Comment: That's weird. Seems like a classloader problem? Maybe could you edit the original question to post the whole trace, and also show the command you're using to run cron?

Comment: Oh the fatal error is my mistake. It's because inside the Civi folder references to non-namespaced classes need to be prefixed. So need to put a \ in front, i.e. `if (is_string($fieldValues)) { \CRM_Core_Error::debug_log_message($fieldValues); }`

Comment: I re-saved the domain info (administer/localisation/languages/currency/locations and since then have had no messages. So if it reoccurs I'll add the \ in.  Thx for help!

Comment: I see you edited the question - do you mean it happened again? If so, did it output anything in ConfigAndLog saying what the value of $fieldValues is? It's possible it's blank, so you would just see a line with date and time and then nothing else on the line, and then in that case you'd need to try to log the value of some other variables in that block to see what's going on.

Comment: I added what was in ConfigAndLog to the question

Comment: I'm not familiar with a setting called "generate_schema_and_data". Do you have any extensions?

Comment: Lots of extensions! 19 in all.  I'll try and find where that message comes from. As I'm only getting the error around once a day then pulling the extensions isn't very practical

Comment: Can you grep the extensions for "generate_schema_and_data"? That might find it.

Comment: The 'ddd DD' and '500' messages comes from the Calendar extension by Agilway. The 'generate_schema' from the Summary Fiellds extension (one of the most popular).  I guess it's the Calendar extension that's the problem, so I'll follow this up.  Do you want to add this as an answer?

Comment: The Calendar extension is at version 1.0 and the current version is 3.4 - Version 1.0 didn't do any version checking.  So I will install the updated version, which should hopefully fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Based on comments this was tracked down to extensions. @andy-clark looked at the installed extensions and an older version of the CiviCalendar extension was creating the string error.

Also the Summary Fields extension was creating deprecated warnings.